# Treating a constructor as a function in Scala - how to put constructors in a map?

Tags: function, scala, constructor

I need to parse some messages. The first 4 bytes of a message identify the type of message, so, using that, I can instantiate an object of the proper type. To make this an efficient operation, I thought I would create a hash map where they key is the first 4 bytes, and the value is the object constructor. I can just look up the constructor and invoke it.

After all, constructors are just functions, and there shouldn't be any problem putting functions in a map. It turns out that I am having some difficulty with this because I don't know how to express the reference to the constructor properly.

To get concrete with a simplified example, suppose we have a message base class, `MsgBase`, and a couple subclasses, `MsgA` and `MsgB`. If I create a companion object for each of the messages and put a factory function into it, I can make the array without any problem using those functions.

Here is a simplified sample which takes the message as a string.

```
class MsgBase(message: String) { }

class MsgA(message: String) extends MsgBase(message) { }

object MsgA  { def makeIt(message: String): MsgA = new MsgA(message)  }
```

and where `MsgB` is similar. Then I can make the map:

```
val cm = Map[String, (String) => MsgBase]("a" -> MsgA.makeIt, "b" -> MsgB.makeIt)

val myMsg = cm("a")("a.This is the message")
```

It seems like I should be able to refer to the message object constructor directly in the expression building the map, rather than using the trivial function in the companion object, but I haven't figured out any way to express that. Is there a way?

Comment: `after all, constructors are just functions` Are they? Who says so? My impression differs. Normally, I can invoke a function multiple times on an object and I don't have to call 'new', just to name the first two differences, which come to my mind.

Comment: @user-unknown yes, constructors actually are (static) functions: (i) the use of 'new' is extra syntax just to remind you that this is a particular sort of function (many languages omit the keyword, including Scala's case-class constructors).  (ii) It's a static method in essence; you don't call the constructor on an existing object (it's not a method).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
"a" -> (new MsgA(_))
```

(all parentheses are needed).

Even if this didn't work, you could of course always define the function explicitly:

```
"a" -> ( (s: String) => new MsgA(s) )
```

Comment: did you mean `"a" -> (new MsgA(_))` ?

Comment: Thanks very much. Just what I was looking for: short form function literal with place holder (p. 191 in Programming in Scala, 2nd ed., in case anyone wants to read more)

Comment: @Kim - I guess it was a string, not a var, so sure, `"a"`.

Comment: So, you are currying the constructor, but, what if the constructor takes no arguments? Is there a shorter way than `"a" -> ( () => new MsgA() )`

Answer (score 3):

For this case it would be better to use case classes, which automatically provide you functions for creating new objects.

```
scala> case class MsgA(message: String) extends MsgBase(message)
scala> case class MsgB(message: String) extends MsgBase(message)
```

So you can refer them just by name, without any syntactical overhead

```
scala> val m = Map("a"->MsgA, "b"->MsgB)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1[java.lang.String,Product with MsgBase]] = Map((a,<function1>), (b,<function1>))

scala> m("a")("qqq")                              
res1: Product with MsgBase = MsgA(qqq)
```

As an alternative approach you can create companion object with overrided apply method by hand. For details see [Programming scala, chapter 6](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch06.html#CompanionObjects)

Answer (score 2):

```
val cm = Map[String, (String) => MsgBase]("a" -> (new MsgA(_)), "b" -> (new MsgB(_)))
```